# Apache HttpComponents EntityUtils memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, apache-httpcomponents

I executed a 12-hour load test on my Java servlet-based server (Java 1.7 running under WebLogic 12 and Oracle Enterprise Linux). After test has finished, I observed that the memory consumption gradually went up from 500Mb in the beginning of the test to around 3.5Gb (and fluctuated there +/- 500Mb for several hours). 3 days later (server was doing nothing during these 3 days) - I examined memory again, and noticed that nothing out of these 3.5Gb was freed.

To make sure GC is executing, I mad explicit GC using jcmd:

- GC.run
- GC.run_finalization
- GC.run

Then, I made a heap snapshot and analyzed with YourKit analyzer (same results with jvisualvm as well).

I noticed that I have 2.5Gb of "Unreachable" objects still being there after 3 days of inactivity. A typical object's incoming references look like this (I'm having ~700K of such objects):

[image]

I examined Apache HttpComponents code (HttpCore version 4.3.2), and I noticed the following strange code in EntityUtils.toString (which I'm using in my server):

[image]

It looks to me that since **reader** object is not closed - it can create references, eventually causing the leaks I'm observing.

- Is this a leaky code of Apache HttpCore EntityUtils?
- Any other reason to have so many unreachable objects after 3 days and after GC.run?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's leaky code. While the `Reader` is not being closed, the act of trying to close a reader normally just closes the underlying stream - which the code *is* doing properly. Laying a reader on top of a stream normally should encourage closing of the reader, as it will close the stream for you as a matter of convenience. But it's not a requirement. Regarding the memory - are you sure you're (1) reading the results properly, and (2) triggering a GC sweep? Unreachable objects are normally *exactly* what the GC will purge.

Comment: @CraigOtis, I'm triggering GC via jcmd <pid> GC.run (followed by GC.run_finalization and another GC.run). It looks like doing something (no failures or errors). Any other way I can reliably execute GC? Thanks.

Comment: You're using YourKit - rather than investigate the snapshot afterwards, try simply attaching YourKit to your Java process at the very beginning of its lifecycle, and turn on memory allocation recording. Not only can you trigger the GC from within YourKit and monitor the memory usage (to ensure it's dropping), but it also may give you a better idea of where that memory's being created and held.

Comment: You are using HttpAsyncClient, aren't you? Why on earth are even using EntityUtils#toString() in the first place? There _massively_ better ways of consuming entity content with both blocking and non-blocking i/o

Comment: @oleg, I like your way of thinking - could you please suggest some clearly better and much more recommended way? Note that the response I'm reading is typically pretty small (1K-5K). Thanks.

Comment: @Semen Semenych posted as an answer

Comment: @CraigOtis, I would love to use YourKit "online", but this target system is not under my control, I can't connect remote profiler to it, so I have to analyze things retroactively. So far - I couldn't find any reasoning for these Unreachable blocks to stay in memory. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider extending `AsyncCharConsumer` as shown [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchangeStreaming.java) to produce a string with response content or using a `HttpAsyncResponseConsumer` if need a more sophisticated response processing.

`EntityUtil` methods are generally intended for entities backed by a blocking `InputStream`. And even then I would generally recommend consuming entity content directly from the content stream instead of converting it to a string.

Comment: This suggestions assumes I should prefer streaming over a blocking read of entire response content. Streaming is good for very large (or unknown-length, or very "chunky" or very slow) response which allows the client to do something with partial data as soon as its available, instead of waiting for entire response to arrive. I'm reading 2K XMLs here, on a local network, so there's not a single benefit of using streaming solution (with all it's overhead), compared to 1-statement EntityUtils.toString call.

Comment: Why anyone use a non-blocking client to end up calling an inherently blocking method to get the result is beyond me. This also causes _multiple_ copies of the same content to get buffered in memory. But so be it.

Comment: The reason is simple - the processing time on the target system is long (minutes), that's why async-client is preferred. But the data is short, so once processing on the target is done - download is almost immediate. No streaming needed.

Comment: This makes little sense given that any decent blocking client will outperform any decent non-blocking as long as the number of worker threads is small (say <500). Not to mention that AsyncCharConsumer gives you both: an event driven architecture and a single copy of content in memory